# How to solve retopology issues

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I've been working on my character sculpting and retopology. I've attached the file that I've been working on. Upon initial inspection, it looks ok, with clean loops, following topology conventions, however I have inadvertently added a lot of spiraling loops. I know that this will cause issues down the line, but I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Example of Topology issues]
[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tIkEvkL14nfcGzzVwFqh0ICpZ1QEj8zu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello, what do you mean by spiraling loops? the topology seems good

Comment: Hi Moonboots, That's what I thought too, but if you try to add edge loops, many of them will loop around, spiral, and generally not follow good edge flow. I think it would be easiest to see, if you install the file. :) Thanks

Comment: Hello ! It would be easier if you could add screenshots to your question which illustrate your problem accurately . It's not really fair to expect people to download random files on the internet. Not trying to be mean, I really think it would increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: in that case you can rearrange the topology in order to break the loop, hard to help without the mesh though

Comment: Hi Gorgious, Thank you for you suggestion, I will change the image to better illustrate my issue when I next have the time. Upon reflection expecting people to install a random file was a bit Naïve of me, and a bit Idealistic.

Comment: Those aren't a problem for animation.  They can make it more difficult to edit your mesh, but if you're doing retopo, you've already finalized your mesh.  I wouldn't worry about them if I were you.